# Is asp.net easier or more stable to use than other open source frameworks, such as Ruby on Rails?

Tags: asp.net, ruby-on-rails, frameworks, web-frameworks

One time I saw an asp.net question on StackFlow, and I just saw that:

71,722 questions tagged for asp.net, 13.7k followers

see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/asp.net

For Ruby on Rails,

36,434 questions tagged ruby-on-rails, 9.4k followers

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ruby-on-rails

So is asp.net close to 40% to 100% the popularity of Ruby on Rails, and how does it compared to Ruby on Rails really?  (good to use, easy, elegant, stable, lots of gems or plugins, lot of gems or plugins that **has** documentation and overview?)

For the programming standpoint, I was thinking that, if asp.net is released every 6 months or 9 months, with a clear cut version, with stable and detailed documentation, then it is actually easier for the programmers because we don't get the "this gem work with Rails 3.0.0 but not with 3.0.6, but you can use this gem, which works for Rails 2.3.11 and up but if you have an older project using 2.3.5, then it won't work.  Or it works for Rails 2.3 but not for 3.0, so let's find something else, or we haven't using this gem but it hasn't been developed or debugged for 5 months and don't know if it works 100% for Rails 3.0 or not and there are 32 issues on GitHub, do we need to use something else?  This gem depends on 5 other gems and has 0 documentation, 0 API spec, 0 overview, 10 lines of installation instructions, and there are 40 files with 3,200 lines of code -- you ask the author on GitHub for documentation, overview, or API spec, or to add it to GitHub, and his answer: read the code.  Is that true for this programming aspect?

Comment: The title of the question is a little misleading since ASP.NET is not an open source framework.

Comment: can't it mean, more stable to use than other frameworks that are open source

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, what libraries you will find for ASP.Net, will work with forward compatibility. Microsoft is much more reluctant to introduce backward compatibility problems than the Rails(or even Ruby) team. That being said, there is not a clear cut framework for plugins for ASP.Net. They all generally have different install instructions and such that must be carried out manually.

My personal opinion:

Ruby provides more elegant code, but I've often seen that doing anything "outside the box" with Rails is less than elegant. I use ASP.Net because of this, and I like C# more as a language than PHP. I prefer the statically(ish)-typed nature of C# for web applications, whereas I use Ruby and PHP commonly for scripting and for small programs/web applications which require little logic. Many people may tell you the exact opposite of this, it is just a matter of opinion

Comment: maybe it can be how elegant, stable, etc.  I am just looking into the comparison in general

Answer (score 1):

ASP.net is more popular on account of (1)Bring a Microsoft Product (2)Great Intellisense in development environment (3)Lots of support and communities. Both products are otherwise good. It just depends on what you are comfortable with.

Comment: but interestingly, I don't hear so much buzzwords about asp.net (close to 0) than I hear about Ruby on Rails.  Also, old recruiters call me up for Ruby on Rails or PHP jobs, but they never asked me or anyone I know who may have asp.net experience

Comment: @動靜能量 this may be because Ruby on Rails is a buzz word in itself, and PHP will probably always be the "common" system. It's been around longer than ASP.Net, and more websites use it.

Comment: You get more of Ruby and PhP calls due to simple law of Economics... Demand & Supply... .Net resource supply is more than Demand and inverse is for Ruby where demand is more than supply. With Azure and other cloud technologies upcoming from Microsoft, there is always plenty of buzzwords and demand for Microsoft Products.

Comment: funny... I was about to start thinking the human world is not based on reason or ethics or moral -- it is more 99% based on demand and supply, and sometimes conscience, if that person has any.  Funny you mention that as well.  But... with so much `.net` resource, why are there still so many questions on StackOverflow?  I thought at a point RoR has so many questions for a simple reason that it is popular.  It is also because gems documentation is not enough and when you `gem install`, it breaks here and there, and people need to ask about it